# Python - direct a functions output to a set

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and was going through this following code which takes in an integer and outputs the positions of 1's in its binary value.

```
def L(encoded_set):
print('{', end = '')
i = 0
if encoded_set:
    while encoded_set % 2 == 0:
        encoded_set //= 2
        i += 1
    print(i, end = '')
    encoded_set //= 2
    i += 1
while encoded_set:
    if encoded_set % 2:
        print(',', i,end = '')
    encoded_set //= 2
    i += 1
print('}')
```

For ex: Binary of 54 is 110110 so the code will output: {1, 2, 4, 5}

Now, i need to direct this output to a set so that i can work with the individual set elements. Something like X[0] = 1, X[1] = 2, X[2] = 4 
and X[3] = 5. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for bit-shifting of value

```
ones = []
pos = 0
while val:
   if val & 1:
      ones.append(pos)
   pos += 1
   val >>= 1
```

Your solution numbers from first non-0 most-significant bit - which may be meaningless unless the position of MSB is known (yes, you know it, but you'll have to add extra code for that). My solution counts position relative to LSB.

Answer (score 0):

As a more elegant way you can convert your number to `binary` with [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) function and use `enumerate` and a list comprehension to return the proper positionsm,and return the list of indices:

```
>>> def pos(num) :
...    return [i for i,j in enumerate(bin(num)[2:],1) if j=='1']
... 
>>> pos(54)
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

*NOTE* that the result of `bin` has a `0b` on leading of the number so you need to loop over the slice of your binary number (`bin(num)[2:]`).